# Display .PHP block on /blog but not inner blog pages

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I have a block which is showing on both my main blog page (/blog) and the individual blog pages themselves.

I'd like to have the block continue to show on the main blog page **but not** on individual blog pages.

For example the block should show on - [this page](http://www.workbooks.com/blog) but not [this page](https://www.workbooks.com/blog/ian-moyse-nominated-top-50-most-influential-people-sales-lead-management).

The blocks .PHP is as follows:

```
<?php 
$path = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '<front>';
$link = url($path, array('absolute' => TRUE));
$findme   = 'blog';
$pos = strpos($link, $findme);
if ($pos !== false) {
  RETURN TRUE;
}
$node = node_load(arg(1));
if($node->type == 'blog') {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to /admin/structure/blocks, search for the name of the block , configure , in the Pages tab , choose "Only the listed pages" , then in the text area write the title of the main blog page

Comment: Sometimes we can be blinded by complication! Thank-you for making me open my eyes!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the php filter option go to the configuration page for the given block.

Under visibility settings, within the 'pages' fieldset. Select the 'Only on the listed pages'. In the textarea underneath enter the path of the blog, in your example 'blog'.
If you wanted this block to appear only on child pages, you could enter 'blog/*' instead.

Alternatively, if this is a programatically created block, within the implementation of hook_block_info. Add the following keys to the block array.

```
'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
'pages' => 'blog',
```

Example

```
function hook_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['example_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Example block'),
    'status' => 1,
    'region' => 'content',
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    'pages' => 'blog',
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
    'weight' => 3,
  );
}
```